# AWS CLI and BOTO3 SDK (permissions issue)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I'm able to download a s3 folder with aws cli like this:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucketname/custom-folder /tmp
```

But I can't list folder files from boto3 library:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

However, I can download a specific file if I know the specific path, which I know because the bash command works correctly:

```
s3.download_file(Bucket='mybucket',Key='custom-folder/1.gz',Filename='/tmp/1.gz')
```

My question is:

How can I download one folder recursively in Boto3 without permissions for reading/listing files in the S3 Bucket ?????

Thanks!

Comment: You run the boto3 from lambda function?

Comment: nop, on a script on my own machine (docker container)

Comment: It sounds like the IAM role is missing the `s3:ListObjects` permission. What is your IAM role configuration?

Comment: I don't know because the credentials are from a third party company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--recursive` command actually needs to list files to know which files to copy. Therefore, it would appear that you *have* been granted permission to list files, but only within `custom-folder`.

You can test this with:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/custom-folder
```

If that works, you could modify your Python app by using:

```py
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='custom-folder/'):
```

This should limit the listing request to just that folder.

If that has a problem, you might need to use the **client** version of the API call rather than the **resource** version.

Comment: Yes, Prefix argument was the key. I add Prefix and I'm able to list all files and subdirectories in the custom folder, thanks!


Although I still don't understand if I made on cli:

`aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/custom-folder`

I get a permission denied:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`